# Unable to access sharepoint even if the access was granted by owner

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I have problem with accessing Sharepoint http://prime21.sharepoint.hpe.com/teams/EMEA_SCO_Handshake. Access has been granted to me by the owner. I was also re-added several times and no success. What can be the problem? I'm rehired by HPE and have different emp ID. Any help or similar cases?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be directed the company's support/IT.

Comment: Are you in the network? This looks and acts like an internal address? There's a lot of points of failure we experienced with our setup, but it was our initial setup for SharePoint Online Hosted. is this url to a MS hosted sharepoint online instance?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reason for this issue.

- Ask your SharePoint farm administrator if your ID is in the User profile Services. Might be your id is not part of it.
- If it is different emp id but what about your user id, is it same? i.e. hpe\username. if it is same then you have to run the move-spuser command to move your old profile from to new profile. `Move-spuser -oldlogin -newlogin`
- You may ask them to remove your user id from that site collection completely and then re add it. They can do it by browsing this url "http://prime21.sharepoint.hpe.com/teams/EMEA_SCO_Handshake/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0" then re add you.

Answer (score 0):

When SharePoint (Office 365) asks for your *Email Address* to log in with, what it's really asking for is your UserPrincipalName (aka UPN). This value might not match what you assume to be your *primary SMTP* address. If it doesn't, and you try to log in with your primary SMTP, it will fail.

Ask your Admin to ensure your UPN and the email you're logging in with match and that your UPN has been sync'd correctly with Office 365. Also, if your UPN has changed recently, it may not have updated correctly in O365.